# Wait for a process to complete in Cmder \ ConEmu

Tags: bash, cmd.exe, conemu, cmder

**Executive Summary:**

For software development debugging purposes, I’m using Cmder 1.3.12 for Windows 10 x64.

If, say, I run in a cmd window `java –jar app2.jar`, I get output logs (inside cmd) and, as expected, the cmd prompt will only become  available when my java process terminates. This is working fine, not only from the command-line but also from inside my calling app (also a java app, let us call it “app1”).

But what I really want is to have a console emulator (I’m using Cmder) where I run my script/app in.
This way, I get features cmd cannot give me, such as larger lines buffer, colored logs (ANSI red colors to clearly show eventual exceptions), multiple tabs and even support for my bash scripts (besides showing my (colored) app logs, it also redirect stdout and stderr to a single log file - for later usage).

However, if I run `cmder /TASK mytask` (which, basically, runs `java –jar app2.jar`) in a cmd window, though it runs smoothly namely by showing my logs inside the featured console, the cmd prompt will immediately become available. Even before the app2 process terminates.
A similar behavior is found if I run `cmder /TASK mytask` from inside my app1.

And this is the problem: I need app2 process to complete before control is returned to app1. Never before!

Seems to me that, somewhere along the Cmder bundle, there’s some kind of stub which launches an application and then immediately exits… Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

>

**Details:**

I’ve done some digging… mytask is a ConEmu bash task: `{bash::mytask}` (same as default `{bash::bash}`, using customized `%cmder_home%\config\user_profile.sh`) which - basically - runs app2 inside Cmder.

For testing purposes, instead of directly calling Cmder, I tried some windows shell instructions which I believe to wait for its command argument to complete before the control returns back to the calling app (besides running them from my “app1”, I also tried running them in a cmd window):

```
start /w Cmder /TASK mytask

call "Cmder" /TASK mytask

cmd /c Cmder /TASK mytask
```

The same (undesirable) results.

Knowing that Cmder is, basically, a bundle of software packages, I continued my investigation:

```
ConEmu -run {mytask}

ConEmu -run "java -jar HelloWorld.jar"
```

I even tried, like before, calling ConEmu with some shell waiting instructions, such as “start /w”.
Still same (undesirable) results!

Finally, I looked over ConEmu Settings for task specific (default) command:

> cmd /c ""%ConEmuDir%..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" --login -i"

Well, bash interactive shells (-i) is not exactly my expertise, so I didn’t try to mess around with additional bash commands\arguments.
Instead, I tried something else (by replacing the entire default command):

> start /w "" "%ConEmuDir%..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" --login –i
>
> call "%ConEmuDir%..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" --login –i
>
> START /w "mytitle" cmd /c java -jar HelloWorld.jar
>
> java -jar ./HelloWorld.jar

Also tried unchecking  `Process ‘start’` from ConEmu Settings Features page (default is checked).

Nothing really worked... Seems to me that, somewhere along the Cmder bundle, there’s some kind of stub which launches an application and then immediately exits… Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

`%cmder_home%\config\user_profile.sh`:

> debug_red()(set -o pipefail;"$@" 2>&1>&3|sed $'s,.*,\e[31m&\e[m,'>&2)3>&1
>
> debug_red "./$CTRL_App_loader_script_name.sh" 2>&1| tee $LOGNAME

These, basically, adds ansi red codes if output comes from stderr and then redirects both stdout and stderr to same $LOGNAME logfile.

```
$CTRL_App_loader_script_name.sh
```

> EXEC_COMMAND="java -Djava.library.path="libs/" -jar CTRL_SENSOR22.jar"
>
> $EXEC_COMMAND

Fixed name and location script. This is created on-the-fly by app1 and just runs my app2.

Comment: Why are you calling `cmder` to start a task and not calling directly the task?

Comment: I tried many possibilities... one was directly calling cmder /TASK mytask, others include: ConEmu -run {mytask} or changing ConEmu Settings Task directly.

Comment: What does the task do? Is it a program, script, or else?

Comment: In the end I just want my app1 to wait for my app2 to finish, while app2 logs are  shown in an "advanced" console emulator. I'm opened to other different suggestions! :-)

Comment: I don't know with what language is written the calling application, but about all of them have the ability to start a process and wait for it to terminate.

Comment: The task runs a customized %cmder_home%\config\user_profile.sh (the default for (bash::bash). This, in turn runs a fixed-name script (created on-the-fly) that runs may "app2" (app1 and app2 are java jars)

Comment: I still don't understand what cmder has to do with running tasks. Please add more details to your post, such as examples of the script, because this is quite unclear.

Comment: I don't think the the calling app language (java) is the issue because I simulated several waitng calls inside a cmd window (in windows 10 desktop).

Comment: I don't think I can edit my post... probably because I'm a new contributor.

Comment: Everyone is supposed to be able to edit his own post.

Comment: %cmder_home%\config\user_profile.sh:

Comment: debug_red()(set -o pipefail;"$@" 2>&1>&3|sed $'s,.*,\e[31m&\e[m,'>&2)3>&1

debug_red "./$CTRL_App_loader_script_name.sh" 2>&1| tee $LOGNAME

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, in order to keep blocked my calling app1 while called app2 is still running "inside" Cmder\ConEmu, `Single instance mode` ConEmu setting has to be unset.

`Single instance mode` setting can be found in the **Appearance** group window of ConEmu settings (Cmder version 1.3.12.915, Windows 10 x64) and is described there as "*use existing window instead of running new instance*".

The fact was that, in order to limit the number of log windows showed in my Windows task bar, I had changed the default (which is unset ;-)).
I'm sure you all agree that this setting could hardly be considered a suspect for this case...

Moreover, one should also take notice if `Close ConEmu with last tab` is set (**Task bar** group window of ConEmu settings). If it isn't, when app2 eventually stops running, app1 will still be kept blocked and the only way to unblock app1 is to manually close that ConEmu window.

Anyway, I would like to thank everyone who took their time reading this question in the hope of being able to help me!

Hope these finds may help someone in the future.